# Send binary file and update a grid with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, telerik, radgrid

I need to handle a user's button click action by sending him a binary file stored in a database and also updating the database and the changes reflect in RadGrid using ajax.

When executing the actions, sending the file and updating the grid, separately it happens just fine, but when trying to do both it returns an error saying the response could not be processed.

I was wondering if is there any alternative to accomplish this.

I have similar pieces of code:

javascript:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             var pbControl = null;
             var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
             prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

             Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()
                                        .add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

             function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                 $(".loads").attr("disabled", true);
             }

             function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                 if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
                     var errorMessage = args.get_error().message;
                         args.set_errorHandled(true);
                         errorMessage = errorMessage.replace(
                          "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:", 
                          "");
                         alert(errorMessage);
                }
                 $(".loads").attr("disabled", false);
              }
        </script>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="loads">
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="Grid" runat="server" 
                    OnItemCommand="Grid_ItemCommand">
                <MasterTableView TableLayout="Auto">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Button" runat="server" 
                                  CommandName="Command" 
                                  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Code") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

c#:

```
protected void Grid_ItemCommand(object sender, 
                                Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Command")
    {
        // Update database
        DatabaseUpdate();
        Grid.Rebind();

        // Send binary
        HttpResponse response = this.Response;
        byte[] bin = GetBinary(code);

        MemoryStream memStream = null;
        memStream = new MemoryStream(bin);

        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
            string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "file.pdf"));
        response.ContentType = string.Format("application/{0}", "pdf");
        response.BufferOutput = false;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        response.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes multiple responses from the server makes a way for them to fight with each other, mainly when you use HttpResponse class. No, problem you can do a trick.
Add an empty page for pushing the file, say `download.aspx`

In your `Grid_ItemCommand` event just remove the code for sending the file. Only do the database updation.

```
 protected void Grid_ItemCommand(object sender, elerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
 {
        if(e.CommandName == "Command")
        {
            // Update database
            DatabaseUpdate();
            Grid.Rebind();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "download","pushFile();", true);
        }
 }
```

the last line in the above code calls a script **pushFile** in `aspx` page and the below script for opening our newly added page `download.aspx`

Javascript:

```
function pushFile()
{
  window.open("download.aspx");
}
```

Then finally in the code behind of `download.aspx` add the below code in `Page_Load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpResponse response = this.Response;
        byte[] bin = GetBinary(code);

        MemoryStream memStream = null;
        memStream = new MemoryStream(bin);

        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
            string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "file.pdf"));
        response.ContentType = string.Format("application/{0}", "pdf");
        response.BufferOutput = false;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this approach, but I think it should work.